# Keras model can only predict a class

Tags: python, keras

#### Summary

I have a binary classification task. After all, the accuracy seems %81, but the model predict only a class.

**Problem:** I understand that the model can't learn much; but why is it predict only a class? And I'm not sure if I do a mistake during data generation. Is anything seem wrong?

#### Info:

- I have an arguably big data (~2 GB). So I train a model with Keras' `fit_generator` method; it doesn't fit on memory and the data probably will get bigger in the future.
- I'm doing my preprocessing and resampling steps inside the generator function.
- The data is imbalanced. I tried to do upsampling (see the code below).
- During training, the accuracy is not increasing; loss is decreasing very little bit.
- This is what I get when I run `classification_report` on a test set (I do the exact same preprocessing steps to test set):

```
UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predi
cted samples.

  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)              
              precision    recall  f1-score   support                                                                                                                                                              

     non-VPN       0.81      1.00      0.89     29432                                                                                                                                                              
         VPN       0.00      0.00      0.00      6973                                                                                                                                                              

   micro avg       0.81      0.81      0.81     36405            
   macro avg       0.40      0.50      0.45     36405                                                               
weighted avg       0.65      0.81      0.72     36405
```

**Codes:**
**Data generator method:**

```
def data_generotto(path: str, batchsize: int):
    while True:
        chunks = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(
            path, "shuffled.csv"), sep=';', chunksize=batchsize)

        for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
            X, y = preprocess.preprocess(chunk)

            # X = np.array(X).reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])

            yield (X, y)
```

**Resampling (among other preprocessing steps):**

```
# sorry for messy code
def balance_train_data(data, fold_count=3):
    """Balance the data using sklearn.utils resample to max sentiment count."""
    balanced_data = pd.DataFrame()
    data_dict = dict(data['label'].value_counts())

    for label in data_dict.keys():
        df = data[data.label == label]
        samples_count = int(
            (max(data_dict.values()) - data_dict[label])/fold_count)
        df_up = resample(df, replace=True,
                         n_samples=samples_count, random_state=42)

        print("Resampled {} tweets: {} + {} = {}".format(label,
                                                         len(df), len(df_up), len(df)+len(df_up)))
        balanced_data = pd.concat([balanced_data, df, df_up])
    return shuffle(balanced_data, random_state=42)
```

**A very simple ANN model:**

```
def create_model(model_folder_name):
    global folder_name
    folder_name = model_folder_name
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', input_dim=4))
    model.add(Dense(4, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

    optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="binary_crossentropy",
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary(print_fn=myprint)

    return model, optimizer.get_config(), "ann"
```

**`fit_generator` function:**

```
    model.fit_generator(data_generotto(
        "./complete_csv", BS), steps_per_epoch=TRAIN_SIZE // BS, epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=[es])

    save_model(model, f"./models/{model_folder_name}/MODEL.h5")
```

Comment: The class imbalance is why only one class is predicted. This isn't really a programming issue.

Comment: Don't you think the resampling should fix this? Do you suggest downsampling?

Comment: You can try resampling, a better approch maybe is to use `class_weight` in keras `fit`

Comment: @SreeramTP I have applied resampling, like I wrote the code above. Do you think is there any mistake about it?

I also will try to use `class_weight` and inform you, thanks

Comment: You can probably try `imblearn` for different methods of sampling and see which one works

Comment: @SreeramTP `class_weight` may have worked alongside of upsampling. Now at least I see a different result and it can predict both classes, even if the accuracy is low. I will search further. Thank you, I can accept this as an answer this if you provide one.

Comment: I have created one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `imblearn` and use different sampling methods from it.

Also, inorder to handle imbalance issue you can try using `class_weight` with appropriate weights while fitting the model.